# CTFontCreateWithName returning ".LastResort" font

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, core-text

I have multiple custom fonts provided with my app, all defined in the app's plist correctly. I can load `UIFont`s with those custom fonts with no problems. `UILabel`s using `[UIFont fontWithName:@"some-custom-font" size:14]` as font work flawlessly.

What doesn't work is CoreText methods. 
I need to use those fonts in attributed strings, so I absolutely need the `CTFontRef`. Till iOS 5 I had no problem what-so-ever. Now, `CTFontCreateWithName` tends to return a font called `.LastResort`, instead of what I need. If I kill the app and relaunch, some of the fonts that failed last time do work now, but others don't. Seemingly random. If I call `CTFontCreateWithName` immediately on app launch, that specific font works later, but again most of the others do not.

I never encountered this kind of behavior before. My app isn't very memory heavy. This feels like some iOS 5 bug. Any help or advice will be very welcome.

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope. Just ignoring fonts that bug out and revert back to a working one. Not good enough, and apparently still happens with 5.1...

Answer (score 1):

I've only used custom fonts via UIKit. You may want to contact DTS, or definitely bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Thanks. I did that, so I will accept this answer if no one posts a better one.

Comment: Does it matter if you get a UIFont for the font first? (Wondering if there's some sort of lazy instantiation bug.)